# Unknown start proc to start my activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I got a strange problem.
First, that's my activity flow

IntActivity -> 111Activity -> 222activity -> 333Activity

Each activity have [Forward] & [Back] button. (software button)
And what I'm doing in [Forward] is: (ie. Int to 111)

```
Intent intent=new Intent(IntActivity.this, 111Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Doing this in [Back]: (ie. 333 back to 222)

```
Intent intent=new Intent(333Activity.this, 222Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Now, user says if they quickly press [Back], sometime when IntActivity has been closed, they'll see
a blank page. looks like 333Activity.

Blank page means it has full UI component, but no any user data inside.
If 333Activity was started correctly, it should filled with user data, and 333Activity ony can be start by 222Activity.

Following is what did I see on logcat

```
INFO/ActivityManager(1321): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy/.IntActivity } from pid 14517
DEBUG/dalvikvm(14517):      GC_EXPLICIT freed 2084K, 56% free 3653K/8199K, external 8158K/10188K, paused 65ms
ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(1321): layer=0xa49520 is not in the purgatory list
INFO/ActivityManager(1321): Process tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy (pid 14517) has died.
// Here, the IntActivity ware been finished due to finish(); or System.exit(0); been called

INFO/WindowManager(1321):   WIN DEATH: Window{40a0cae8 tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy/tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy.111Activity paused=false}
INFO/WindowManager(1321):   WIN DEATH: Window{40a2a828 tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy/tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy.IntActivity paused=false}
INFO/ActivityManager(1321): Start proc tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy for activity tw.com.xxxx.android.yyyy/.333Activity: pid=14535 uid=10105 gids={3003}
```

Check the last line of log, it's not "Starting activity", but "Start proc".

I still don't know what exactly going on...any ideas or suggestions are welcome :)

My devices are:
HTC DesireHD in android 2.2 (will not have this problem I posted)
HTC DesireHD in android 2.3.3 (shows this problem I posted frequency)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong here:
Starting an activity with intent is ok, but coming back to activity which is already started once, is doing wrong for you.As android maintain back stack log for activities started.

Activities work like stack of cards, 1st activity --> 2nd activity --> 3rd activity
Doing back with android provided back button, it goes like in reverse order, you don't have to fire another intent for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply first, I do know what you said, and that's what I did before. But in my APP, there will max 7 activities stack. I got low memory issue due to this... That's why I did close current activity when start a new activity.

Comment: 7 Activities is fine to handle... But you should look for possible solution to overcome low memory issues, but don't change way android works. Low memory issues i understand is hard to solve, but that's headache you have to bear it.. Low memory issues due to images used ?

Comment: I still don't know...after last activity been finish(), even been System.exit(0).....and another activity been called up.  Don't know who did that "Start proc".  If an activity been started by an intent, the log should looks like "Starting activity...", not "Start proc". Did you have any idea about this ?  Thanks :)